# In the simple sentence “He made her disappear,” what part of speech is “disappear?”

Tags: parts-of-speech

In the simple sentence “He made her disappear,” what part of speech is “disappear?”

Could also just be “To make disappear.”

Answer (score 2):

In the sentence "He made her disappear.", the word disappear is a bare infinitive verb. The phrase "her disappear" is a bare infinitive clause.
The bare infinitive is used with certain main verbs, like "make", as described here:
[Thoughtco "bare infinitive"](https://www.thoughtco.com/zero-or-bare-infinitive-1692621)

> The zero (or bare) infinitive is used after verbs of perception (see, feel, hear), many auxiliary verbs (may, should, must), the verbs **make** and let, and the expressions had better and would rather.

(emphasis added).

The phrase "to make disappear" is a to-infinitive phrase that isn't grammatical without a subject (such as the word "her" in your example). It can be use to refer to "make disappear".

With a different main verb, the infinitive clause can be a "to-infinitive", for example, in "He wants to disappear."